# How do I force drop a table from my schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

I destroyed an Account model and a multi-step rollback to remove the corresponding accounts migration in the db has also been done. However, when I do rails db:reset, an accounts table is automatically added along with a note on pending migrations:

```
    Dropped database 'db/development.sqlite3'
    Dropped database 'db/test.sqlite3'
    Created database 'db/development.sqlite3'
    Created database 'db/test.sqlite3'
    -- create_table("accounts", {:force=>:cascade})
       -> 0.0131s
    -- create_table("accounts", {:force=>:cascade})
       -> 0.0084s
```

Is there something I am missing here? I removed associations in the other models before deleting/rolling back/resetting the db.

Comment: Additional information: Schema maintains account table. Something seems stuck and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved through the below steps (not completely sure why this order worked):

1. Rake db:migrate:status to see that there was a no file migration with the same number as the migration on the scheme.
2. Rake db:migrate:down VERSION=[that matched the no file status and schema]; this failed and the output was No migration with version number: XXXX.
3. Rails db:reset
4. Rake db:migrate:status (no file migration at this point was no longer on the list)
5. Rails db:migrate:reset
6. Rails db:migrate and everything was back to normal.